# My question was migrated to Super User but I think it was an inappropriate decision

Tags: discussion, migration

Today I asked [a question](https://superuser.com/questions/1499034) about the possibility of a file/folder being hidden by a malware such that Windows thinks it doesn't exist. My question was migrated to Super User without any explanation immediately.

I think that my question is indeed a security related question because it is relevant to hooking, rootkits and modifying Windows kernel and it asks about ways to undo the damage. I think that security experts can answer this question better than most users on Super User. So, I'd really appreciate it if my question is migrated back to the security subdomain where it can be answered properly.

Answer (score 6):

While there *might* be all kinds of malware/rootkit/hooking/kernel elements to your situation, that's not what you asked.

What you *asked* was how to find a file you couldn't find. That's a SuperUser kind of question.

If you were asking *how* malware could hide files in the filesystem and still access them, then that's a security question. But asking how to troubleshoot your system is a SuperUser question.

Comment: While I agree that the wording of my question was not optimal, but I won't go as far as saying that I was only asking for troubleshooting. My questions had two parts: 1- Is it possible to modify Windows in a way that it deliberately hides a file system even though it exists, 2- if possible, how can it be undone?  Anyway, that aside, if I edit my question and make my question clear, can I ask for it to be remigrated to here?

Comment: Both of those questions are still not security questions but more focused on the Windows filesystem

Comment: Besides, the answers you have are the most likely : check your antivirus logs